# Inequality regarding non-negative real numbers.

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are $n$ non-negative real numbers and for some $p>1,q>1$ with $1/p+1/q=1,$ such that
$$ n\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_j)^p\right)^{q/p}<1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
Does this imply
 $$ n\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j\leq 1? $$ 
I tried as following:
\begin{align}
&n\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_j)^p\right)^{q/p}<1 ~\Rightarrow~ \sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_j)^p<\frac{1}{n^{p/q}}~{\color{Red}\Rightarrow}~  (a_j)^p<\frac{1}{n^{p/q}}\\ &\Rightarrow a_j<\frac{1}{n^{1/q}}~\Rightarrow~ \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j=n^{1/p}
\end{align}
I think I loose too much at red implication. Kindly help in proving or providing counter example.

Comment: but your sum is in breckets and the $n$ stands bevor the sum

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$ satisty inequality (1). It don't think your choice of $a_j's$ satisfy (1).

Comment: @Suhail Now I understood you. See my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\frac{1}{p}=\alpha$ and $\frac{1}{q}=\beta$.

Hence, $\alpha+\beta=1$ and by P-M we obtain:
$$1>n^{\frac{1}{q}}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=n^{\beta}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)^{\alpha}=n^{\alpha+\beta}\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_j^\frac{1}{\alpha}}{n}\right)^{\alpha}=$$
$$=n\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_j^\frac{1}{\alpha}}{n}\right)^{\alpha}\geq n\cdot\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^na_j}{n}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^na_j$$

A counterexample is $a_1=a_2=...=a_n\rightarrow\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I don't understand the last but one step of the solution. What is P-M (inequality)?

Comment: @Suhail It's Power Means. See here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality